# Issue while translating from javascript into c#

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to translate my 'Caesar Cipher function', which I wrote in Javascript into C#.

My Problem, so far seems to be getting the letter, after the Code conversion is pushed into my final array... I could really need some good advice here.

```
using System;

class caesar_cipher
{

private static string caesar(string input, int n)
{
    n = n % 94;

    string cipher = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        input = input.Replace("Ä", "Ae");
        input = input.Replace("Ü", "Ue");
        input = input.Replace("Ö", "Oo");
        input = input.Replace("ß", "ss");
        input = input.Replace("ä", "ae");
        input = input.Replace("ü", "ue");
        input = input.Replace("ö", "oe");

        int code = ((int)input[i]);

        if (code >= 33 && code <= (126 - n))
        {
            code = code + n;
            char crypt = Convert.ToChar(code);
            cipher = cipher.Concat(crypt, cipher);
        }
        else if (code > (126 - n) && code <= 126)
        {
            code = ((code + n) % 94);
            char crypt = Convert.ToChar(code);
            cipher = cipher.Concat(crypt, cipher);
        }
        else
        {
            cipher = cipher.Concat(input[i]);
        }

    }

    return cipher;
}

public void Main()
{
Console.WriteLine(caesar("Hello, World", 13));
Console.WriteLine(caesar("Äste in Österreich sind übermäßig große Äste!", 7));
Console.WriteLine(caesar("z", 5));
Console.WriteLine(caesar("1234567890", 283));
Console.WriteLine(caesar("KEIN LIMIT!!!", 940));

}

}
```

Comment: Why are you modifying `input` with the `Replace` call result for each character in input when you're not updating input in the rest of the for's body?

Comment: I don't think you need to replace those characters in `input` every time the loop executes. You can just do that once.

Comment: Good catch, i fixed that! Though it doesn´t solve my Problem :/

Comment: Exactly what is your problem? Can you show us what output you are getting, and show us what output you expect to get?

Comment: Does this compile?

Comment: main.cs(29,20): error CS0176: Static member `string.Concat(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead
main.cs(35,20): error CS0176: Static member `string.Concat(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: main.cs(39,20): error CS0176: Static member `string.Concat(object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead
error CS5001: Program `main.exe' does not contain a static `Main' method suitable for an entry point
Compilation failed: 4 error(s), 0 warnings

Comment: @DanielBöhme,Like i said, it does not compile

Comment: Yes, but how can i fix that?

Comment: Are the following your expected output?

`Uryy|9 d|!yq`
`Hlz{l pu Vvz{lyylpjo zpuk |lilythlzzpn nyvzzl Hlz{l(`
`!`
`23456789:1`
`KEIN LIMIT!!!`

Comment: Yes, this is also the output i managed to get in Javascript. I guess in C# i have to use the Concat differently or a other Method a i am not aware of yet.

Comment: @DanielBöhme, I have just fixed a couple of lines in your method will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate strings in C# with the `+` operator:

```
string s = "foo";
s = s + " bar";

char c = 'x';
s = s + c;
```

But for this kind of thing, where you repeatedly concatenate additions onto the same string in a loop, we often use the `StringBuilder` class:

```
private static string caesar(string input, int n)
{
    //  Emrah Süngü's answer makes this part nicer, though it won't 
    //  make any difference at runtime. 
    input = input.Replace("Ä", "Ae");
    input = input.Replace("Ü", "Ue");
    input = input.Replace("Ö", "Oo");
    input = input.Replace("ß", "ss");
    input = input.Replace("ä", "ae");
    input = input.Replace("ü", "ue");
    input = input.Replace("ö", "oe");

    n = n % 94;

    StringBuilder cipher = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        int code = ((int)input[i]);

        if (code >= 33 && code <= (126 - n))
        {
            code = code + n;
            char crypt = Convert.ToChar(code);
            cipher.Append(crypt);
        }
        else if (code > (126 - n) && code <= 126)
        {
            code = ((code + n) % 94);
            char crypt = Convert.ToChar(code);
            cipher.Append(crypt);
        }
        else
        {
            cipher.Append(input[i]);
        }

    }

    return cipher.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! That is a clean Solution, and i also learned something new too :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your solution is `cipher.Concat` method. You can not use it like this, it will not compile anyways. What you are looking for is`string.Concat`. However when working with `string` please keep in mind that it is an immutable class. So it is better to use `StringBuilder` class.

```
namespace StackOverFlow {

    using System;
    using System.Text;

    internal class Program {

        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine(Caesar("Hello, World", 13));
            Console.WriteLine(Caesar("Äste in Österreich sind übermäßig große Äste!", 7));
            Console.WriteLine(Caesar("z", 5));
            Console.WriteLine(Caesar("1234567890", 283));
            Console.WriteLine(Caesar("KEIN LIMIT!!!", 940));
        }

        private static string Caesar(string input, int n) {
            n = n % 94;
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(input);
            stringBuilder.Replace("Ä", "Ae").Replace("Ü", "Ue").Replace("Ö", "Oo").Replace("ß", "ss").Replace("ä", "ae").Replace("ü", "ue").Replace("ö", "oe");

            var cipher = new StringBuilder();

            for(var i = 0; i < stringBuilder.Length; i++) {
                var code = ((int)stringBuilder[i]);
                char crypt;
                if(code >= 33 && code <= (126 - n)) { code = code + n; crypt = Convert.ToChar(code); }
                else if(code > (126 - n) && code <= 126) { code = ((code + n) % 94); crypt = Convert.ToChar(code); }
                else { crypt = stringBuilder[i]; }
                cipher.Append(crypt);
            }
            return cipher.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```